# Looking for tutorial Script# 0.8+

Tags: script#

Hi I have problem because i see a lot of out of date tutorials about Script#.
I am trying to learn this. But i cant make simple page. This is my script.
I dont knew how amd pattern. Works exactly but assume i need to set as src ss.js.
Second question. In this version of script# i dont see deployment path.
I need to manualy set build out to Script folder.

```
    Element x = Document.GetElementById("save");
    x.AttachEvent("onclick", delegate()
    {
        Window.Alert("Hello world except IE");
    });
```

This page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SimplePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimplePage.SimplePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 222px">

        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="ll" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
            <input id="name" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" Height="30px" Text="Save" />
        </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="Scripts/HelloScriptSharp" src="Scripts/required.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mscorlib.debug.js"></script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Edit I tried to compile examples from repo but they wont compile.My code compile but dont work.
Ok i compiled(but with errors). This helped me https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/340.
Edit 2. I compiled but there was problem with deploying scripts. So i manualy moved them.
But i am still working with my example. It compile atm but event dont execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't updated tutorials for version 0.8, but I'll be working on a getting started (and more) tutorial on the [scriptsharp wiki](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki). Let me know if you have any suggestions on what you'd like to see covered.

As for the deployment path issue, check [this thread](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/349) which also redirects you to look at the [check-in notes here](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/commit/21af186664764be30c0afb073e0da0347bd3312b). Here's [another issue](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/300) that might be of historical value related to deployment path.

Here's an article on [getting started with the development branch](https://github.com/theoutlander/scriptsharp/wiki/Using-the-development-branch).

EDIT:

Here's my first pass at a series of tutorials: [Hello World](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Creating-your-first-HTML5-Application%3a-Hello-World)

Second EDIT:

Here's my second article on [Building a spreadsheet in Script# (HTML5)](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Building-a-spreadsheet-in-Script%23-using-HTML5)